# Is there another way to use SqlNotificationRequest?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, service-broker

I have a simple application which listens to the SQL notifications via `SqlNotificationRequest`. Because of some reasons and limitations I can't use `SqlDependency`. (according to [SqlDependency limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx))

As you know using `SqlNotificationRequest` needs to handle all the stuff, including at least a thread to read notification messages from database.

**Is there any way to discard the threading and make an Event-Driven structure for this?** I mean the .net client do nothing except waiting for an event to be fired by SQL Server like `SqlDependency`.

Comment: At the end of the day, the client needs to execute a command on some thread to receive the notification message.  This can be a background thread that executes a blocking call, polls or both (blocking call with timeout like SqlDependency).  Just raise an event when the message is received.

Answer (score 1):

The limitations of `SqlDependency` come from the limitations of Query Notifications. [`SqlNotificationRequest` also uses Query Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) and will hit exactly the same limitations.

Comment: I don't mean to use `SqlNotificationRequest`, I assume to use Service Broker in SQL side, but what mechanism in .net side to avoid continuous checking.

Comment: From .Net: connect to the server and issue [`RECEIVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx).